# How do I return part of the url using window.location.hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am really stuck

I am currently using the code below to add the name of a dynamically loaded page to the url

```
var value = $(this).attr('href');

    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.hash = value;
```

it almost works as its returning this in the url

http://www.sitename.com/dev888/#http://www.sitename.com/dev888/page-name

But I the only want part of the url to return like the example below

http://www.sitename.com/dev888/#/page-name

How can I edit the code above to get my desired result?

Thank!!

Comment: Try this:

`var value = this.href;
value = value.substr(value.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, value.length);
window.location.hash = value;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play with the value to get the last one like this

```
var value = $(this).attr('href');

    e.preventDefault();
    var parts = value.split("/");
    value = parts[parts.length-1]; 
    window.location.hash = value;
```

Or you can change the `attr('href')` to the value you want directly :)

I hope this can help

And you may want to take a look at pusState

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Answer (score 0):

The browser already does this for you. Just make your link's `href` the hash, and let the user click it normally:

```
 <a href="#my-hash">Click!</a>
```

It will automatically append `#my-hash` to the URL.

Trying to accomplish this with JavaScript is totally wrong, unless you require logic to prevent the click under certain conditions, and even then the correct behaviour is to specify your hash as the href of the link, conditionally allowing the click event to be handled by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you find interesting to obtain the title of the page and use it in the hash

```
var current_title = $(document).attr('title');
e.preventDefault();
window.location.hash = current_title ;
```